# Entering dash between numbers in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to insert a dash between even numbers. However, the program returns nothing when run. When I set the initial list to contain a number, it returns that same number indicating the loop isn't adding anything.

```
function dashEvenNumbers(numbers) {
  var list = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    if (numbers[i] % 2 == 0 && numbers[i + 1] == 0) {
      list.push(i, '-');
    } else {
      list.push(i);
    };
  };
  alert(list);
  return list.join('');
};

alert(dashEvenNumbers(123125422));
```

Comment: The line with if (numbers[i] % 2 == 0 && numbers[i + 1] == 0) { is missing the second remainder check

Comment: In the `if()` statement you  have `numbers[i + 1] == 0` that avoids to enter in the `if()` since you have not a zero in the number passed as parameter

Comment: variable numbers is array in the function . But u pass a number

Comment: @Jamb000h You may edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numbers don't have a `length` property so `numbers.length` will be `undefined`.

You probably want to cast to string first, e.g.:

```
numbers = String(numbers);
```

Comment: Thanks, along with converting the number to string, I also fixed other mistakes that were stopping the code. For some reason, I thought javascript converted all input into strings.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regular expression with look ahead.

```js
console.log('123125422'.replace(/([02468](?=[02468]))/g, '$1-'));
```